# IBM MQ call failed with comp code '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED') from spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ibm-mq

**we are using spring boot to send a message to ibm mq manager on a remote server, and for Authentication we use SSL certificate + we use cipher suite to cipher data**

**Question**:  why we get this error although we not use credentials for authentication and we use ssl instead  ?

the code is simple , this in method in the main application spring boot class

```
 @PostConstruct
        public void listen() { 
          System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "true");
          System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", sslkeyr );
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", sslkeyr );
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", sslpass );
            System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
            System.setProperty("jdk.security.allowNonCaAnchor", "true" );
          System.out.println("start sending message ....");
            //ProducerService producerService=new ProducerService();
            producerService.sendMessage();
            
            System.out.println("start sending message sent success ....");
        }
```

-and this is the properties file

```
 server.ssl.key-store=/home/user/file.jks
    server.ssl.key-store-password=pass
    server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
    
    jdk.security.allowNonCaAnchor=true
    
    ibm.mq.queueManager=qmName
    ibm.mq.channel=channel
    ibm.mq.connName=ip(port)
    ibm.mq.sslCipherSuite=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
```

Hint : i used ibm sample code ( https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-tls-ssl-wizard/blob/master/com.ibm.mq.ssl-wizard/src/tlswizard/samples/SSLSampleJMS.java)with the same properties, configuration and jks file
to send message (but not spring boot app) and successfully message sent and received by the MQ but the problem appear when we used spring boot

Comment: With a 2035 it is always best to check the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` to see what the cause was. How does `server.ssl.key-store-password=pass` map to `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", sslpass );`?

Comment: the log tell the same message that the client should be sure about username and password ,@Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}") private String sslpass;  @joshMc

Comment: Read the README for the Spring boot starter. It tells you that the default configuration will use a default user/password, and how you should set properties to NOT send that by instead explicitly setting a blank user in the properties.